# Animating an arrow that points to <li> based on position on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I not very familiar with html, css and javascript

I am using twitter bootstrap, I'd like to have a section indicator in a long page that shows the relative position of the current view relative to the entire ver long scrollable page.

The sample of what I want to achieve is in: 
http://global.tommy.com/int/en/Collections/start

I managed to do that with `<ul> <li>`, however, I'd also like to animate the arrow movement from one `<li>` to the next `<li>` as the user scroll up and down within the page. I managed to scope out the code for the `<ul> <li>` but have no idea how to animate the movement... could anyone help me point to the specific animation part or recommend some javascript or css library for that? Probably I missed twitter-bootstrap elements too, however I did not find any so far... Thanks!

EDIT:

My code in jsfiddler, however, it doesn't seem to work in jsfiddler:

[The ul li code](http://jsfiddle.net/xjauF/)

What I wanted to achieve is exactly like the animation on the left side of Tommy Hilfiger's page when you scroll up and down, the arrow will keep track of which section you are in by adjusting the arrow's position pointing to the specific section on the li

Comment: please share what you done so far... if possible with a jsfiddle demo

Comment: thanks! I've inserted the source code to jsfiddle, although it doesnt seems to work there, however, it does work in the website: http://global.tommy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail I can't really go into specifics, but I can at least suggest [jQuery's animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It makes animating css properties very easy.

Comment: thanks! however, the global.tommy.com version doesn't seem to use jquery... do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

To animate the scrolling of the page, take a look at this library:

https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav.git

you can use the same js to animate the movement of the arrow as well